# Can a plasma ball light up minerals that fluoresce?

Tags: electromagnetism, physical-chemistry, plasma-physics, fluorescence

I want to know if I could use a plasma ball to light up a UV poster that are typically activated by blacklights.

#### option 1: using light from the globe

According to my research it seems that the light produced from a plasma ball would be the wrong wavelength as blacklights produce light at [20 nm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklight), plasma balls are [filled with halogens](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/inert-gases-in-plasma-balls) which produce light of [higher wavelengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen_lamp#Spectrum). (please correct me if I'm wrong)

#### option 2: using EM from the globe

I wasn't exactly sure how to research EM's effects on minerals that fluoresce, but plasma globes have [this effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56767/what-causes-fluorescent-light-bulb-to-light-up-when-it-is-near-a-plasma-globe-c/56774#56774) on fluorescent light bulbs. Perhaps if I touched the poster to the ball it would fluoresce?

Comment: you've asked if they produce blacklight, then stated that they don't and you have researched this? whats your goal here?

Comment: 20 nm is in the soft x-ray range. I would hope your blacklight is not producing that.

Answer (score 2):

In the title you asked the following question:

> Can a plasma ball light up minerals that fluoresce?

The plasma in a plasma ball surely emits some UV-A radiation (probably not much though) besides the visible light (note, blacklight is also referred to as UV-A light and ranges from $315-400\,\mathrm{nm}$, the value you stated seems to be wrong).

Your problem will be, however, that the glass surrounding the plasma ball (or *plasma globe*, the expression I am more used to) often blocks the UV radiation. So you will probably have a hard time trying to let your minerals fluoresce (but worth a try, I would say as plasma globes are cheap and fun to use).

You also mentioned that a fluorescent lamp lights up when being close to plasma globe - that is a different story and related to the gas inside of the lamp being ionized by strong electric fields (varying in time, RF fields) very close to the plasma globe.